# Rolling sum based on date variable

Tags: r

I want to sum all values for a variable for the past 3 months according to exact day for each ID. There might be 2 obs for some ID, 70 obs for another ID etc. For example, on April 15 I want to look all the way back to the January 16 and sum all values on this interval including January 16 and April 15. There could by 2 observations on this interval or even 70.

The window size is therefore never the same which means I can't use rollapply from the zoo package.

Here is a small example data with expected output.

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), date = c("01/01/2015", "01/02/2015", 
"15/02/2015", "01/03/2015", "01/04/2015", "01/01/2015", "01/02/2015", 
"15/02/2015", "20/02/2015", "01/03/2015", "14/03/2015", "01/04/2015", 
"01/01/2015", "10/02/2015", "15/02/2015", "20/02/2015", "25/02/2015", 
"01/03/2015", "10/03/2015", "20/03/2015", "01/04/2015"), value = c(106, 
57, 43, 105, 180, 109, 36, 102, 97, 97, 113, 83, 178, 19, 80, 
167, 40, 5, 30, 124, 8), expected = c(106, 163, 206, 311, 385, 
109, 145, 247, 344, 441, 554, 528, 178, 197, 277, 444, 484, 489, 
519, 643, 473)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Look up `padr` package. This package will allow you to pad an interval with NA values so that you have the same number of observations for each period for each ID. Then you can use rollapply or another windowing function.

Comment: There are other methods to do this with series and joins if you don't have access to `padr` but they are a lot uglier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We convert the `date` to actual `date` object, `group_by` `id` and for each `date` find out the dates in the group which lie in last 3 months and take `sum` of their respective `value`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(ans = purrr::map_dbl(date, ~ sum(value[
             date > (. -  months(3)) & date <= .])))


#      id date       value expected   ans
#    <dbl> <date>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 2015-01-01   106      106   106
# 2     1 2015-02-01    57      163   163
# 3     1 2015-02-15    43      206   206
# 4     1 2015-03-01   105      311   311
# 5     1 2015-04-01   180      385   385
# 6     2 2015-01-01   109      109   109
# 7     2 2015-02-01    36      145   145
# 8     2 2015-02-15   102      247   247
# 9     2 2015-02-20    97      344   344
#10     2 2015-03-01    97      441   441
# … with 11 more rows
```

Comment: This looks like it will work for small data sets, but will be very slow for large data sets. Still a good method depending on your needs.

Comment: yeah since we are comparing each date value in the group to all date values in the group.

Answer (score 2):

The `width` in `rollapply` can be a vector of widths and we can compute those using `findInterval`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(date), 
         expected2 = rollapplyr(value, 
          width = 1:n() - findInterval(date - months(3), date), 
          FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 21 x 5
      id date       value expected expected2
   <dbl> <date>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1 2015-01-01   106      106       106
 2     1 2015-02-01    57      163       163
 3     1 2015-02-15    43      206       206
 4     1 2015-03-01   105      311       311
 5     1 2015-04-01   180      385       385
 6     2 2015-01-01   109      109       109
 7     2 2015-02-01    36      145       145
 8     2 2015-02-15   102      247       247
 9     2 2015-02-20    97      344       344
10     2 2015-03-01    97      441       441
# ... with 11 more rows
```